# job ssis in ssms versus local solution

Tags: ssis

I have a job ssis that truncate a table and insert into this table.
When i launch the package in visual studio, all works well but when I put the job on sql server and launch it with ssms, it doesn't works. there is a primary key conflict when inserting..so i'm asking why its working in visual studio and not on sql management studio..

I log one table after the truncate and the count return 0 rows..so the truncable command works well.

I use the same user to launch the package in visual studio or ssms.
I use ole db datasource and destination.

here is the complete error message :

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\USER. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.5149.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  14:46:04  Error: 2018-10-11 14:46:08.01     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Data Flow Component OLE DB Destination [104]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_STA_TABLE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.STA_TABLE'. The duplicate key value is (19).".  End Error  Error: 2018-10-11 14:46:08.01     Code: 0xC0209029     Source: Data Flow Component OLE DB Destination [104]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2018-10-11 14:46:08.01     Code: 0xC0047022     Source: Data Flow Component SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (104) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (117). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2018-10-11 14:46:09.50     Code: 0xC02020C4     Source: Data Flow Component Data Source T_TABLE [2]     Description: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.  End Error  Error: 2018-10-11 14:46:09.50     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: Data Flow Component SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Data Source T_TABLE returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  14:46:04  Finished: 14:46:10  Elapsed:  5.781 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Thank you.

Comment: based on your error, it does not look like it is a job agent issue, did you check it the deployed package has the same tasks in it as the on you ran in VS?

Comment: Hello, yes i already check the file and the path in the job. this is the one that i build with vs

Comment: The duplicate key value is `19`.   Check to see if the destination table already has a `19`.   If it doesn't, check to see if your source data has two rows with `19`.

Comment: Hey, I verify and i have no duplicate value. The table source has this column in primary key.

Comment: The row with id "19" is the first row, is it possible that my task begins and the "truncate table task" is not finish before it?

Comment: Ok I found my error. I have a sequence container with many packages inside and one of the package file was the same than another..
Thank you all.